# Java : String Check for null and two attributes

Tags: java

I have a String in which i was checking 3 conditions 
        // str!=null 
        // Or if str contains rate attribute 
                // if the str contains undefined

i have tried this way , its working but please let me know if this is a valid way to pass ??

```
package com;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {


        String str = "{\r\n" + 
                "    \"qty\": \"undefined\",\r\n" + 
                "    \"dswer\": 0,\r\n" + 
                "    \"bag\": {\r\n" + 
                "        \"dm\": \"2\",\r\n" + 
                "        \"rate\": \"---\",\r\n" + 
                "        \"ghy\": \"3013-04-05T00:00:00.000-05:00\",\r\n" + 
                "        \"dee\": \"301304\",\r\n" + 
                "        \"desc\": \"SSAA APR 05 2013 --- CALL\"\r\n" + 
                "    }\r\n" + 
                "}";



        if(str!=null && str.contains("\"rate\": \"---\"") || str.contains("undefined"))
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Valid");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I'd mentioned in your previous question itself, to parse your `JSON`. That would reduce a lot of work and would look more cleaner too!

Comment: Why would you print valid if you string is `null`?

Comment: i think you need to switch valid and invalid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change `str != null &&` to `str == null ||`:

```
if(str==null || str.contains("\"rate\": \"---\"") || str.contains("undefined"))
```

Otherwise, the string becomes valid when it is `null`.

Comment: if str is null , will it not throw NPE ??

Comment: @PreethiJain No: if it's `null`, the rest of the condition will not be evaluated, because of short-circuiting.

Comment: No it won't! The evaluation will **Short-Circuit** there.

Comment: @PreethiJain no. check the condition again.

Answer (score 1):

try this way

```
if( str!=null 
      && ( str.contains("\"rate\": \"---\"") || str.contains("undefined") ) )
{
      System.out.println("Invalid");
}
else
{
      System.out.println("Valid");
}
```

As per your code even if str is null, it will still check for contains

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(str==null)
{
  System.out.println("Invalid");
}
else
{           
  if(str.contains("\"rate\": \"---\"") || str.contains("undefined"))        
  {         
    System.out.println("Invalid");       
  }         
  else          
  {             
    System.out.println("Valid");            
  }     
}
```